# JSON.parse SyntaxError with multiple values on same key

Tags: json, parsing

Here is my sample JSON data:

```
var testData =
{
"Level1": [
    {
        "Level2": [
            {
                "Level3": [
                    {
                        "body": "AAAAA"
                    },
                    {
                        "body": "BBBBB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
```

When I use `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
var x = JSON.stringify(testData).replace(/[\[\]]/g,"");
console.log(x);
```

It works as expected and correctly replaces the square brackets and returns this result:

```
{"Level1":{"Level2":{"Level3":{"body":"AAAAA"},{"body":"BBBBB"}}}}
```

The error occurs when I try to add `JSON.parse` like this which returns an error:

```
var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testData).replace(/[\[\]]/g,""));
```

The specific error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON`. What seems to be happening is that `JSON.parse` is treating the comma inside the key/value list as the end of the JSON string, when it is not the end.

[image: JSON.parse error]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The initial blob **IS** valid JSON, You are breaking it by removing the objects from the array.

Comment: To get the value `AAAA` you would use something like: `JSON.parse(theString)['Level1'][0]['Level2'][0]['Level3'][0]['body']`

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I know that the initial blob is valid JSON, but I am trying to use JMESPath so that I can extract and transform data.  For some reason, my JMESPath expressions do not work on JSON when there are square brackets.  That is why I am trying to remove them.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I do not know what JMESPath is, but by removing the _square brackets_, this is no longer valid JSON, so I would assume that any interpreter in the middle, would fail, like JS is.

Comment: Ok, I now understand where you are coming from.  I tried your suggestion to use `JSON.parse(theString)['Level1'][0]['Level2'][0]['Level3'][0]['body']` and this returns `[object Object]` and this SyntaxError `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

Comment: That failure is on the JSON.parse, before it even tries to access the object. You passed this one invalid JSON from the start ;) The string you passed begins with a `o` instead of `{`

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.  I meant to say that the `[object Object]` error occurred when I tried to add `JSON.stringify` like this:  `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(testData4)['Level1'][0]['Level2'][0]['Level3'][0]['body']);`  I'm just trying to figure out how I can get the value `AAAA` and not `[object Object]`.

Comment: Well with that, you are trying to convert a single string, 'AAAAA' into a JSONObject. `var body1 = JSON.parse(testData4)['Level1'][0]['Level2'][0]['Level3'][0]['body'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
{"Level1":{"Level2":{"Level3":{"body":"AAAAA"},{"body":"BBBBB"}}}}
```

This is not valid JSON

The level 3 should be:

```
"Level3":[{"body":"AAAAA"}, {"body":"BBBBB"}]
```

For you first levels, you have arrays with only 1 element, so the array brackets `[]` kan be removed without consequence. The level 3 is an actual array with 2 elements, so removing the `[]` breaks your valid JSON syntax.